# Find duplicates in array of hashtables

Tags: powershell

I have an array of hashtables and I need to find if there are elements who has the same `Name`.

I have this `HasDuplicate` function which return `True` or `False` if the array contains duplicate or not.

What I am doing here is that I am iterating through each element and add `Name` of it to another array, and then check it if it `exists`. But this code does not looks good, and I was thinking if there is another way of achieving this

```
# object looks like this
$array = @(
    @{ Name = 'First', Passed = $True }
    @{ Name = 'First', Passed = $False }
)

Function HasDuplicate
{
    param($array)
    $all = @()
    foreach($item in $array)
    {
        $item_name = $item.Name
        if($all -contains $item_name)
        {
            Write-Error "Duplicate name ""$item_name"""
            return $True
        }
        else
        {
            $all += $item_name
        }
    }
    return $False
}
```

Comment: Please define "good looking"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Group-Object is probably the easiet, something like this:

```
$array = @(
    @{ Name = 'First'; Passed = $True }
    @{ Name = 'First'; Passed = $False }
)

$array.Name | Group-Object | Where-Object Count -GT 1
```

Comment: I think you mean -GT 1

Answer (score 0):

Another way you could do it using an hash table:

```
$array = @(
    @{ Name = 'First'; Passed = $True }
    @{ Name = 'First'; Passed = $False }
)


$h = @{}
$array | % {$h[$_.Name] += 1 }
$h.GetEnumerator() | Where value -GT 1
```

Answer (score 0):

This might not be very good looking compared to the other answers, but you could just count your names in another hashtable then output the duplicates afterwards.

```
$array = @(
    @{ Name = 'First'; Passed = $True }
    @{ Name = 'First'; Passed = $False }
);

# Count names in array
$counts = @{}
foreach ($object in $array) {
    $name = $object.Name
    if (-not $counts.ContainsKey($name)) {
        $counts[$name] = 0
    }
    $counts[$name] += 1
}

# Output duplicates
foreach ($name in $counts.Keys) {
    if ($counts[$name] -gt 1) {
        Write-Output ("Duplicate Name: " + $name)
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Duplicate Name: First
```